# Jquery in firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug, code-snippets

Having a persistent problem with Jquery in firebug...frequently I'll type some 
JQuery statement into the firebug console and it won't work, I'll try to load a
JQuery Object into a variable and will just get an 'undefined' error.

I found a code snippet somewhere in a Stack Overflow comment that makes everything work, its something like

```
($){
    //all of your JQuery goes here
}(JQuery);
```

...
Something like that. This piece of code definitely makes all my JQuery go, I just can't understand why. Possibly it has something to do with namespaces or something? I have been cutting and pasting it from bookmark to scripts for a while, kind of would rather have insight. I see some sample scripts in Stack Overflow that include this code, and some that don't. I have the Apress JQuery and the Firebug books, neither one mentions it. I have the JQuerify plugin to firebug, and mostly work on Drupal sites which include JQuery by default.  Still need this code to make things work.

So My question is -- what is the purpose of this code, what is it called (so I have a search term aside from just browsing this site hoping for code that includes it) and is there any reason to think that its necessary to make a JQuery script work in the firebug console? If there's not, is there some deeper issue that this code addresses, and are there other ways to address it?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to use jQuery on the Firebug console, you need to make sure that jQuery is actually loaded. If you're on a page that uses jQuery, you're good to go. Otherwise the library first needs to be included (`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`).

If the `$` shortcut is used by another library, you're still able to use the global "jQuery" named variable. To restore the `$`, you can put your code in a closure:

```
(function($) {
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

But don't confuse this syntax with the shortcut for jQuery's ready event (I'm not really sure what you're referring to with that code snippet):

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: So when you're testing a script in firebug, would you include a library call within the script?

Comment: Also, have you seen this snippet? I'm really curious what its purpose is -- its all over, including on stack overflow, but I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: If I just want to run a quick test on the console, I normally go to jquery.com (sure they use their own library on their page...) or I use jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the code I'm talking about -- That's a way of reclaiming the $?  I guess something else must be grabbing it (no idea what that could be).

Comment: But normally you wouldn't expect to need that closure (function($) {//...})(jQuery);, I must just be having really crappy luck, or something in Drupal must grab the $...(Thanks for the jsfiddle tip too)

Comment: @user173361 If the second snippet is what you were looking for, here is more about it: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - it's basicalley jQuery's ready event, that executes your code when the DOM is all loaded and ready so that you're able to work with it.

Comment: No, only if there is a conflict with another library or the global variable named `$` is used otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I've been able to use the onready before, must just be running into a conflict (now to trace it) Thanks again, big help